# python-attrs: validator in child class

Tags: python, python-attrs

Using the Python module attrs, I'm trying to have a subclass with a condition on its attributes more restrictive than its parent, like in the minimal example below.

```
import attr

@attr.s
class Base:
    x = attr.ib()
    y = attr.ib()

@attr.s
class Child(Base):

    @x.validator
    def _x_validator(self, a, x):
        if x < 0:
            raise ValueError()
```

Defining a validator like above raises an error (`NameError: name 'x' is not defined`).

I've found a workaround by redefining `x` in the child class.

```
@attr.s
class Child(Base):
    x = attr.ib()

    @x.validator
    def _x_validator(self, a, x):
        if x < 0:
            raise ValueError()
```

However it messes up the ordering of the attributes.

```
In [5]: Child(5, 10)
Out[5]: Child(y=5, x=10)
```

So, finally, I ended up redefining all the attributes in the child class (and there are more than two in the actual code).

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I have no experience with `python-attrs` (which IMHO is a typical "not such a good idea" ie something that tends to creates more problems than it solves and makes code more complicated than it has to be), but anyway: have you tried `@Base.x.validator` ? Note that I actually don't think it will work as intended (I suspect it will apply the validator to `Base.x`, hence to `Base` and all of it's subclasses).

Comment: Also note than adding restrictions to a child class breaks the Liskov's substitution principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) so your child class is no longer a proper subtype of  it's parent. It's not necessarily a problem in Python where inheritance is not required for subtyping, but I thought I'd better mention it since it might reveal a design issue.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, the simplest workaround I found was simply not to use a validator in the child class:

```
@attr.s
class Child(Base):
    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        assert self.x > 0
```

---

Thanks to bruno desthuilliers for rightly pointing out Liskov principle.
Note that the problem does not only occur for `@x.validator` but also for other constructs such as the attribute default value `@x.default`. It seems that the upcoming `dataclass` for Python 3.7 [works slightly better with inheritance](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#inheritance) than `attrs` in this case.